# Create cascading Listbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The question is simple. I would like to create a drop menu of list of elements calling back the item selected using Tkinter. Is that possible?

[image: listbox]

Comment: You mean a [combobox](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#combobox)?

Comment: *Is that possible?* Yes. I'm thinking you want more to that answer. Well, so do we in your question.

Answer (score 0):

#It is possible! It's actually called an OptionMenu in Tkinter.

```
    window = Tk()
    
    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set("Choose Option")
    drop_menu = OptionMenu(window, clicked, "option1", "option2", "option3", "option4")
    drop_menu.pack()


    window.mainloop()
```